# Obj-C, app moving around UIImageView's but need to return to the view and reset positions?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I've probably setup the UIImageViews incorrectly. I added them in interface builder. I then allow them to be moved around the view with touchbegan etc.

I'm using a navigation controller and I need to have the positions of the UIImageViews reset to how they were positioned when the view was loaded.

I thought I could re-initialize them in viewWillAppear, but I don't seem to be able to do this.

Can someone advise me what I should do to make this functionality work?

Comment: What triggers the re-initialization?

Comment: Nothing at the moment, I wasn't sure if I'd need to, or I could just call init etc.

Comment: How do you load the nib file? Is it connected to a view controller?

Comment: Yes, its loaded as its set in the vc nib settings.

Comment: I mean the vc is set in the nib settings

Comment: Well if you don't mind the overhead you could just recreate your viewcontroller. But as you stated, you are using a navigation controller, so this seems tricky. You could of course wrap the view controller in a new controller which is on the nav controllers stack. You could do the reload of the view controller in the wrapping one, without interfering with the nav controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to store the positions somewhere. You could even subclass the UIImageViews and put in a custom property like `CGPoint initialPosition`.

You could as well load the nib file again and try to map the UIImageViews you find in it to the ones you are currently showing, but personally I'd stick to some local storage.

Comment: I think the idea of storing the positions, but I think I'd rather use CGPoint NSArray, although I haven't figured out how.

Comment: You can only store objects in an array. So use `NSValue valueWithCGPoint:`. The problem you are facing is: how do you match an index to the imageView? You could go for a dictionary, set tags for your images and use those as keys. You'll have to convert the tags to string to use those as keys.

Comment: Oh I hadn't thought of that, I'm using IBOutletCollection, although I guess it doesn't matter they are all the same images etc, just different positions.

Comment: I think looping through the IBOutletCollection and storing the points in a cgpoints array should be alright. You could of course set incrementing tags to the images while you are looping and use those as index.